# Regex with powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, plex

I am writing a powershell script to notify me if two users are using the same username but different IP when playing from a plex server.

I managed to get an xml display of current connections that are steaming at that time.

What I need to do is to come up with a reg expression where I extract the User id and IP address and then I can do a search to see if there are duplicate user ID and that has different IP.

I managed to find the regex for IP addresses which is '\b\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\b’

But having a hard time to extract the User Id from it as well. Note the User ID will always be numbers but no set limit.

Here is the example of the data

```
<User id="13456" title="usersmith" />
<Player address="2.2.2.2" device="Windows" machineIdentifier="a9b222ef940"
```

Comment: For User ID: `^<User\s+id="([^"]+)"`, `\1` has the ID..

Comment: is there anyway to only take the ID number and not the User id as well? Also correction I tried the syntax on the full data and it didnt find anything but found it when only using the above data, here is the full string for User id  <User id="1" thumb="https://plex.tv/users/a51d" title="bob" />

Comment: You have an xml document, so use an xml parser. Regex is the wrong tool for this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would parse this as xml, ex:

```
#$xml = [xml](Get-Content myfile.xml)
#$xml = [xml](Invoke-WebRequest ... whatever).Content
$xml = [xml]@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<User id="13456" title="usersmith" />
<Player address="2.2.2.2" device="Windows" machineIdentifier="a9b222ef940" />
</root>
"@

$xml.root.user.id
```

but if you really want regex, try @heemayl's solution except the start-of-line `^`-anchor which might not fit your real xml-data (in that case you've provided bad sampledata). Ex:

```
if('User id <User id="1354" thumb="plex.tv/users/a51d"; title="bob" />' -match '<User\s+id="([^"]+)"') { $Matches[1] }
```

Comment: I don't have to use regex, as long I  able to get the string in a variable so I can do a comparison.

Comment: Either way I've shown you both solutions. You choose :-)

Comment: Going to give it a try later tonight, just finishing from work, will report back. thanks

Comment: so I gave it a try and I think the example I was providing didnt really have everything, so I am still having issues using the xml parse. Here is the full data which I want to loop through and get the User ID and IP address.

Comment: Did you try yourself? The "property-path" for that is `$xml.MediaContainer.Video.User.id`. You just need to follow the nodes until you reach the target... :-)